# Can I make order unimportant when localizing a timedelta?

Tags: python, pandas

If I localize a `datetime()` object after it has been passed through `pandas.Timedelta()`, it has the correct date, time, timezone and timezone offset.

However, if I localize a `datetime()` object before it has been passed through `pandas.Timedelta()`, it's timezone offset is relative to the unaware `datetime()` object.

I wasn't expecting order to be important.  Is there a way that I can make order unimportant?

```py
import pandas
import pytz
import datetime

unaware_date = datetime.datetime(2023,3,12,17)

unaware_timedelta_date = unaware_date - pandas.Timedelta(weeks=110)
aware_and_localized_unaware_timedelta_date = pytz.timezone('EST5EDT').localize(unaware_timedelta_date)
print(aware_and_localized_unaware_timedelta_date)

aware_and_localized_date = pytz.timezone('EST5EDT').localize(unaware_date)
aware_and_localized_timedelta_date = aware_and_localized_date - pandas.Timedelta(weeks=110)
print(aware_and_localized_timedelta_date)
```

```
2021-01-31 17:00:00-05:00
2021-01-31 17:00:00-04:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `localize()` considering DST transitions. For `EST5EDT` latest transition was on Sun 12-Mar-2023 at 02:00:00 A.M. So if your timedelta moves `unaware_date` before this transition then you will get this 1 hour difference.

If you don't want to consider DST then you may use `replace(tzinfo=...)`:

```
import pandas
import pytz
import datetime

unaware_date = datetime.datetime.now()

unaware_timedelta_date = unaware_date - pandas.Timedelta(weeks=110)
# aware_and_localized_unaware_timedelta_date = pytz.timezone('EST5EDT').localize(unaware_timedelta_date)
aware_and_localized_unaware_timedelta_date = unaware_timedelta_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('EST5EDT'))
print(aware_and_localized_unaware_timedelta_date)

# aware_and_localized_date = pytz.timezone('EST5EDT').localize(unaware_date)
aware_and_localized_date = unaware_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('EST5EDT'))
aware_and_localized_timedelta_date = aware_and_localized_date - pandas.Timedelta(weeks=110)
print(aware_and_localized_timedelta_date)
```

Output:

```
2021-02-01 17:21:33.430799-05:00
2021-02-01 17:21:33.430799-05:00
```

Comment: Also you can compare `localize()` and `replace(tzinfo)` outputs using different timedeltas. e.g. your final date >= March 12, 2023 02:00:00AM then offset is 4 for both cases. You can check offsets here -  https://www.prokerala.com/travel/timezones/EST5EDT?mode=history. It is history of DST transitions and tz offsets for `EST5EDT`